# How to make MvcSitemapNode visible only in google sitemap but not in menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I want to make some some nodes in my Mvc.sitemap to be visible only in google sitemap, there is no needs to display them in menu.

Is there any way i can achieve that?

Probably i need somehow to play with attribute [visibility](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced%20node%20visibility&referringTitle=Home)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Advanced Node Visibility](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility) on the GitHub Wiki, you have to change the visibility provider to FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider and add "visibility" to attributesToIgnore:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true"> 
    <providers> 
        <clear /> 
        <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" 
          type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
          ...
          attributesToIgnore="visibility" 
          ...
          siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
        /> 
    </providers> 
</siteMap>
```

When this have been done you have to add the visibility attribute to all the nodes you want to hide. The attribute should be set to:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Only in SiteMap" ... visibility="XmlSiteMapResult,!*" />
```